# How enable dragging a file on the *.exe and get it as parameter?

Tags: c++, windows, parameters, drag-and-drop, executable

What do I have to do to make my program use a file that has been dragged and dropped onto its icon as a parameter?

My current `main` method looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "ERROR: Wrong amount of arguments!" << endl;
        cout << "\n" << "Programm closed...\n\n" << endl;
        exit(1);
        return 0;
    }

    Converter a(argv[1]);
    // ...

    cout << "\n" << "Programm finished...\n\n" << endl;

    // cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is select 10 (or so) files, drop them onto the EXE, and process them from within my application.

---

**EDIT:**

The incomming parameter is used as filename, constructed in the cunstructor.

```
Converter::Converter(char* file) {
       // string filename is a global variable
   filename = file;
   myfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);
}
```

The method where the textfile gets read:

```
string Converter::readTextFile() {
char c;
string txt = "";

if (myfile.is_open()) {

    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        myfile.get(c);
        txt += c;
    }

} else {
    error("ERROR: can't open file:", filename.c_str());
}
return txt;
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**
deleted

**Update:**
I got again to this point.

Actual `Main` method:

```
// File path as argument
```

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout
            << "ERROR: Wrong amount of arguments! Give at least one argument ...\n"
            << endl;
        cout << "\n" << "Programm closed...\n\n" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        exit(1);
        return 0;
        }

```
vector<string> files;

for (int g = 1; g < argc; g++) {
    string s = argv[g];
    string filename = "";
    int pos = s.find_last_of("\\", s.size());

    if (pos != -1) {
        filename = s.substr(pos + 1);

        cout << "argv[1] " << argv[1] << endl;
        cout << "\n filename: " << filename << "\n pos: " << pos << endl;
        files.push_back(filename);

        }
    files.push_back(s);
    }

for (unsigned int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++)
    {
    cout << "files.at( " << k << " ): " << files.at(k).c_str() << endl;
    Converter a(files.at(k).c_str());
    a.getATCommandsFromCSV();
    }


cout << "\n" << "Programm finished...\n\n" << endl;

cin.ignore();

return 0;
}
```

Actually the console window apears for maybe 0.5 sec and closes again.
It doen't stop on any of my `cin.ignore();` Maybe it doesn't get there?

**Can anyone help?**

Comment: See my answer below and feel free to ask any questions related...

Comment: I had a problem that was similar to this. I added `std::cout << "pause";` before the loop that iterates through arguments, and somehow it started working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your program does not need to do anything special apart from handling command-line arguments. When you drag-drop a file onto an application in Explorer it does nothing more than to pass the file name as argument to the program. Likewise for multiple files.

If all you expect is a list of file names, then just iterate over all arguments, do whatever you want with them and be done. This will work for zero to almost arbitrarily many arguments.

Comment: I tried with just one file and it did nothing... The program (console window) appeared for < 1sec. and nothing happened. In contrast giving the parameter manually through the console works fine. Thats why I'm asking...

Comment: @Beasly: You do realize that the console window disappears as soon as your program finishes running? Put a pause in there or wait for a keypress so you can see the output.

Comment: Yes I do ;) The thing is, I manipulate a text file and save it with another name. Example: input: test.txt output: text_c.txt - actually this file isn't made. As I said manually it works...

Comment: @Beasly: Does your code have problems anywhere with certain characters, such as spaces? Explorer will almost certainly pass the complete, absolute path to the file instead of just the file name. Also, you might be creating the new file in the program's working directory, which is not necessarily next to the original file.

Comment: Do you mean spaces in the file path? So do you think I should try to cut the String into filename only and try this?

Comment: @Beasly: I have no idea what exactly your code does, but as I wrote, you shouldn't need to do anything exceptional to support dragging files onto your application icon from Explorer. I just cobbled together a simple program that just dumps the arguments to the console and I get all dropped files as arguments to the program. Since you are observing what files get created I suspect that something goes wrong there and the new file gets created where it shouldn't. Although Explorer apparently sets the working directory to the directory where you dragged the files from (at least on Win 7).

Comment: @Beasly: Essentially you would need to support two scenarios, I guess: 1. The argument is just a relative path to a file (or just the file name) in which case you probably resolve it against the current working directory. 2. The argument is an absolute path to a file, in which case you probably only want to change the file name and not the whole path for the output file.

Comment: I'm trying to see what actually is passed as argument. But the program closes it self immediatly after dropping a file. Even if I put "cin.ignore()" or "system("pause")" before returning...
If I open the program without argument it stays with it's error msg. I inserted some more code to the Q for more background information...

Comment: @Joey it doesn't stop even with getchar();

Comment: ok program stops now... i'm working on it... will post my process as soon as I have some results

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could write a test program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // argv[0] is not interesting, since it's just your program's path.
    for (int i = 1; i < argc, ++i)
        cout << "argv[" << i << "] is " << argv[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And see what happens after you throw different files at it.

---

**EDIT:** Just look at Joey's answer.

Comment: +1 anyway. From the comments on my answer we're exactly at that point now again: Writing a test program that outputs the arguments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to the main question

**TO SEE THE ANSWER TO YOUR LAST PROBLEM SEE BOTTOM OF THIS ANSWER**

All drag&dropped files are get-able as `argv[orderOfTheFile]` (`orderOfTheFile` is from 1-n),

*however* how does windows create that order, now **that** is a real mystery...

Anyway let's say I would create 26 plain text files ( **.txt* ), from `a.txt` to `z.txt` on my Desktop, 

now if I would *drag&dropped* them on my `ArgsPrinter_c++.exe` located directly on `C:\` drive,

an output would be similar to this:

```
argc = 27
argv[0] = C:\ArgsPrinter_c++.exe
argv[1] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\c.txt
argv[2] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\d.txt
argv[3] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\e.txt
argv[4] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\f.txt
argv[5] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\g.txt
argv[6] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\h.txt
argv[7] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\i.txt
argv[8] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\j.txt
argv[9] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\k.txt
argv[10] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\l.txt
argv[11] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\m.txt
argv[12] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\n.txt
argv[13] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\o.txt
argv[14] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\p.txt
argv[15] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\q.txt
argv[16] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\r.txt
argv[17] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\s.txt
argv[18] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\t.txt
argv[19] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\u.txt
argv[20] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\v.txt
argv[21] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\w.txt
argv[22] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\x.txt
argv[23] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\y.txt
argv[24] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\z.txt
argv[25] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\a.txt
argv[26] = C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\b.txt
```

My `ArgsPrinter_c++.exe` source code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
   cout << "argc = " << argc << endl; 
   for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
      cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << endl; 

   std::cin.ignore();
   return 0; 
}
```

## Your last problem

I have created a simple program that creates only a sceleton of your class so it can be used, and **the program's main *itself* ran JUST FINE** => if your program exits too soon, the problem will be in your class...

Tested source code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Converter{
    public: 
    Converter(const char* f){ cout << f << endl; }
    void getATCommandsFromCSV(){ cout << "called getATCommandsFromCSV" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
  vector<string> files;

  for (int g = 1; g < argc; g++) {
      string s = argv[g];
      string filename = "";
      int pos = s.find_last_of("\\", s.size());

      if (pos != -1) {
          filename = s.substr(pos + 1);

          cout << "argv[1] " << argv[1] << endl;
          cout << "\n filename: " << filename << "\n pos: " << pos << endl;
          files.push_back(filename);

          }
      files.push_back(s);
      }

  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++)
      {
      cout << "files.at( " << k << " ): " << files.at(k).c_str() << endl;
      Converter a(files.at(k).c_str());
      a.getATCommandsFromCSV();
      }

  cout << "\n" << "Programm finished...\n\n" << endl;

  cin.ignore();

  return 0;
}
```